# When are Chebyshev centroids and "analytic" centroids equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization, linear-programming

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $x,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
The intersection of a finite number of halfplanes in $n$ dimensions can be expressed as the solution set to a system of linear inequalities: $Ax \leq b$.

This also characterizes a polytope: an $\mathcal{H}$-representation of a polytope $\mathcal{K}$ (each row of $A$ defines a hyperplane, and the inequality is it's associated half-space). Just to simplify things, I just want to think about irredundant ($\mathcal{K}$ is expressed with a minimal number of halfspaces), closed, convex polytopes, and normalized (rows of $A$, so the projection-distances from an interior point $x$ to the $i$-th plane is just $b_i - a_i^Tx$) $\mathcal{H}$-representations.

The Chebyshev Centroid is defined as the point which maximizes the minimum projection-distance to any one hyperplane (alternatively, the centroid of the largest sphere inscribed in $\mathcal{K}$). It can be recovered by solving a linear program:

$$
\max r \text{ s.t. } a_i^Tx + r \leq b_i \quad \forall i
$$

On the other hand, the analytic centroid is canonically defined as the point which maximizes the product of the projection-distances to each hyperplane:
$$
\arg \max_x \prod_{i} b_i - a_i^Tx
$$
Both are unique for closed, convex, irredundant polytopes. My question might be pretty basic, but it would be great to get a better idea. I just want to know when the analytic centroid is exactly the chebyshev centroid, and if not, if there is a way to estimate the difference between the two.

One thing that's easy to see geometrically is that if $\mathcal{K}$ is a cuboid (or any "regular" polytope: angles between adjacent hyperplanes are equal, and line-segments characterizing the border of $\mathcal{K}$ are of equal length), the notions of centroids are equivalent. One relaxation that I think also works is that all that's needed is the equi-angular condition (e.g. $n$-dimensional rectangle.) Alternatively, the centers are the same for a rhombus as well...

I'm pretty sure in the general case there is basically nothing you can say about the correspondence between the two, but are there any interesting special cases? Are there ways to think about this geometrically, or a way to show under what conditions the solutions to those optimization problems are the same?

Maybe a related question in 1-dimension is asking when

$$
\arg\max_xx^m\prod_ia_i = \arg \max_x [\min_i x\cdot a_i]
$$

I'm sorry if any of this is incorrect or incoherent. I just learned about these concepts and was thinking about this.

Comment: Cuboid is a pretty strong thing to ask for. A much weaker condition of _central symmetry_ suffices, and even that is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks! Agree that central symmetry works. I'm curious if you have a simple example for a non-centrally symmetric shape for which the CB = AC.